# Ansible: set_fact after successful variable match in array

Tags: variable, array, ansible, set

I have following playbook `~ # cat demo.yml`:

```yaml
- name: demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    set:
      task:
        type: var1
    task:
    - type: var1
    - type: var2
    - type: var3
  
  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: set

  - debug:
      var: task

  - set_fact:
      task: 
        type: "{{set.task.type if item.type is search(set.task.type|join('|')) else 'absent'}}"
    loop: "{{task}}"
  
  - debug:
      var: task
```

**Output:**

```json
PLAY [demo] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "set": {
        "task": {
            "type": "var1"
        }
    }
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "task": [
        {
            "type": "var1"
        },
        {
            "type": "var2"
        },
        {
            "type": "var3"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [set_fact] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'type': 'var1'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'type': 'var2'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'type': 'var3'})

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "task": {
        "type": "var1"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

As you could see this works great and new value for variable `task.type` is set to **var1**.

However the problem is when I provide `set.task.type: var4` or any other variable.

Than `task.type` is set to **var4** instead of **absent**.

**Question:**

How to set new value `task.type: absent` if `set.task.type` does not match any values from the array?

Comment: Your loop redefines the values of `task`. During the first execution, `task` is a list that contains three items. After the first iteration of your `loop`, `task` is a dictionary. Don't try to re-use the variable name like that and you will probably see different behavior.

Comment: I'm also a little unclear on the logic you're trying to implement, so if you could explain that a bit more clearly that would help.

Comment: Why do you want to introduce this `absent` state if you can check for `is defined`?

Comment: I'm trying to verify if variable set.task.type is on the list of task.type. If value is present than I need to update  task.type to value from set.task.type.
This woks great until I provide  set.task.type value that does not exist on task.type array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it is also unclear what you are try to achieve, however, regarding your question

> *How to set new value `task.type: absent` if `set.task.type` does not match any values from the array?*

and

> *This woks great until I provide `set.task.type` value that does not exist on `task.type` array* (annot.: list)

this seems to be because of the filter `| join('|')` on the dictionary, as well the `loop` which seems to be unnecessary to me. So for how to

> *verify if variable `set.task.type` is on the list of `task.type`. If value is present than I need to update `task.type` to value from `set.task.type`.*

perform without a loop

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    # dictionary
    set: 
      task:
        type: var4

    # list
    task:
    - type: var1
    - type: var2
    - type: var3

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ set.task.type if task | join('|') is search(set.task.type) else 'absent' }}"
```

which will just result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: absent
```

Please take note that you are **not set a new value** but creating a new object instead. There will be no list `task[*].type` but a dictionary `task.type` after.

**Further Documentation**

- [`update_fact` module – Update currently set facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/update_fact_module.html)

  > *Variables are not modified in place, instead they are returned by the module.*

Comment: that woks great! thank you!